# python xlwt tries to overwrite existing sheet rather than create new sheet

Tags: python, debugging, exception, xls, xlwt

I have a simple app with a GUI that takes in a number of presets, runs some tests on them, and saves the results to an excel sheet. My problem is, each time I change the presets and hit the button, the program attempts to overwrite the data that was created in the last test, rather than create a new sheet like I want it too. Here is some code.

```
data_book = xlwt.Workbook( encoding = "utf-8" )

def TEST():
    ### Irrelevant code that does a few calculations ###



    # Prepare data storage

    #data_book = xlwt.Workbook( encoding = "utf-8" ) commented out, same code outside of function 

    sheet = data_book.add_sheet( str( loc ) + "N"+ str( N ) + "d" + str( dis ) ) #names the sheet using values from UI
    sheet.write( 0, 0, "Title" ) #title the sheet
    for i in range( 10 ): #small number for debugging
        for a2 in A2:
            sheet.write( i+1, 3, a2 )
            sheet.write( i+1, 2, eng.test( wav_arr[ i ], A1, a2, N ) ) 
            sheet.write( i+1, 1, txt_arr[ i ] ) 
            sheet.write( i+1, 0, dt.now() ) 
    # Save sheet to workbook       
    data_book.save( "test"+str( d.today() )+".xls" )
    print "data saved. Test complete."
    clear( master_arr )

# this is the button, calls the test when pressed
b = Button( master, text = "Test!", command = lambda: TEST() )
b.pack()
```

I am not sure how to overcome this. As you can see, I have tried moving the creation of data_book inside the TEST() function, but that didn't help. Maybe a try-except block that explicitly creates a new sheet when the overwrite exception rises? But I thought I already explicitly create a new sheet when the button is clicked. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Maybe add a time stamp to the  sheet = data_book.add_sheet( str( loc ) + "N"+ str( N ) + "d" + str( dis ) + TIME) . Then each sheet will have a different name?

Comment: Thanks Tim. I thought that would be the issue, but varying the values of loc, N, and dis resulted in the same exception ( I believe varying these values achieves the same end as what you're suggesting?)

Comment: Yup, that's what I had in mind. Glad you got it sorted!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue. For whoever is interested, look at the nested for-loop around the sheet.write() functions. Notice that the way the index is set up, the function is commanded to write to the same cells for every value in the array A2. This causes an exception as the program attempts to overwrite cells.